# PyDev fails to initialize with error "could not connect to 127.0.0.1:XXXX"

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm trying to debug my Python application using `Eclipse` with `PyDev` installed. I can run my python code but I can't run it in debug mode. This is what I got :
[image]

I'm pretty sure it is not a firewall problem since Java debugger runs fine.(Java debugger also relies on network connection) And running Eclipse as root doesn't help at all. What is happening?

Comment: Perhaps you need to give permission to PyDev in your firewall ? Is that exact port open ? Run   os.system("ping " + "-n 1"+ " " + host)

Comment: I tried sudo, didn't solve the problem...

Comment: Did you run the code I asked you to run ?

Comment: Your line runs fine.

Comment: ok then can you post your code thati s giving you problems?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jg6k4J2m